# google map on Android Emulator Behind Proxy

Tags: android

I m facing the problem of accessing **Maps of Android Emulator**. I am working on **Android emulator 2.3.1** (Google API) API 9.

The problem is i am working behind corporate proxy. Emulator doesnt allowed to open Google Maps. It gives error :

> this application requires active data connection

I have tried with the command line options but it didn't work, i don't have an android phone so the second options not there for me.
I had set the proxy settings in the emulator but that's not working with maps etc.

Only browser works. Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the fact that i got the same problem as you, and then i searched and put the same question as u. But sadly, someone told me that, connect internet via proxy in android emulator does not support connecting to google map.This also happen with connect to web service via proxy.